What do BFS trees tell use about their graph of origin
Let $G = (V, E)$ a connected graph. Let $\mathcal{B}_x(G) \subseteq G$ be the BFS tree with root vertex $x \in V$. Since $G$ is connected, $\mathcal{B}_x$ contains all vertices of $V$.
Informally, I will say two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic, and denote it with $G_1 \simeq G_2$, if they have "the same shape". For example, a square with vertices $\{1, \ldots, 4\}$ is isomorphic to the Hasse diagram of the poset $(\{2, 4, 6, 12\}, \mid)$
I was drawing graphs today and came to the following idea, which may be known theory if true.

If $G$ is regular then $\mathcal{B}_x \simeq \mathcal{B}_y$ for any $x, y \in V$.

Informally, all BFS trees derivable from a regular graph are the same. This may be an obvious statement, but it sparked my curiosity about what BFS trees reveal about their graphs of origin. For example, take the following symmetrical graph:

The graph contains two squares "mirrored" by a crossed diamond. All "reflecting" nodes ($0$ and $11$, $12$ and $3$,
$13$ and $2$, $1$ and $10$) span the same BFS tree.
This example is artificial, but in larger or more complex graphs it would perhaps mean something to find a family $S \subseteq V$ of vertices that span the same BFS tree. Is there any theory around matters such as the ones I have described?
I'm relatively new to discrete math and these things occurred to me spontaneously today, so please excuse if $a$. this is totally irrelevant of $b.$ theory already exists.

It's not even true that breath-first search trees generated from the same root vertex are isomorphic. Consider the following graph, building a BFS tree from vertex $0$. Then $1$ and $2$ are adjacent to $0$, and $4$ is adjacent to $2$, but is $3$ adjacent to $1$ or $2$? It's an arbitrary choice that will yield non-isomorphic trees.

So let's modify your question a bit: if $G$ is regular, then for any two vertices $x$ and $y$ on $G$, is it possible to construct isomorphic BFS trees whose roots are $x$ and $y$?
Recall that a BFS tree has the property that the distance between the root and any other vertex in the tree is the same as the minimum distance between them in the original graph. So for $B_x$ and $B_y$ to be isomorphic, we require that for every distance $d$, there are $i$ nodes with a minimum distance to $x$ and the same number of nodes with a minimum distance to $y$ in $G$. Even for regular graphs, there are counterexamples where the graph doesn't have this kind of symmetry. For example, consider a carbon nanotube as a $3$-regular graph, or construct a $3$-regular graph that is not $2$-connected.

It is always nice to hear from someone curious, interested in discrete maths.
I will preface this with the note that I am not familiar with any literature relating to your thoughts. However, I do not believe your statement about regular graphs to be true. Below is a 3-regular graph, but a BFS tree rooted at the leftmost vertex is not isomorphic to one rooted at one of the two middle vertices; the two trees you obtain have 5 and 6 leaves respectively.

For your question posed at the end, a BFS tree already tells you a lot of information about neighbours, non-neighbours, and distances from the root. But I am unsure what to say other than this. It is an interesting question.
